# jQuery does not work in widget backend

Tags: widgets, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I created a widget which should use jQuery for switching between two views and implement the jQuery UI date picker.

I was wondering why my jQuery code does not work as I noticed that the date picker isn't working either. The console neither throws errors nor warnings.

This is my code inside the widget class:

```
function form($instance) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-datepicker', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/styles/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core'));
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery.ui.theme', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/styles/jquery-ui.css');
}
```

Is there any known issue? Or do I have to take something into account?

**EDIT**

And this is in a main backend script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#widget-so_calendar_excerpt-range_from').each(function() {
        console.log(this);
        $(this).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy'});
    });
});
```

Something quite strange is going on here. When I reload the admin panel, every time the console log changes. It looks like this (each line one page reload):

```
[Log] <input class=​"widefat hasDatepicker" id=​"widget-so_calendar_excerpt-range_from" name=​"widget-so_calendar_excerpt[range_from]​" type=​"text">​ (backend.js, line 28)
[Log] input#widget-so_calendar_excerpt-range_from.widefat (backend.js, line 28)
[Log] <input class=​"widefat hasDatepicker" id=​"widget-so_calendar_excerpt-range_from" name=​"widget-so_calendar_excerpt[range_from]​" type=​"text">​ (backend.js, line 28)
[Log] input#widget-so_calendar_excerpt-range_from.widefat (backend.js, line 28)
[Log] <input class=​"widefat hasDatepicker" id=​"widget-so_calendar_excerpt-range_from" name=​"widget-so_calendar_excerpt[range_from]​" type=​"text">​ (backend.js, line 28)
[Log] input#widget-so_calendar_excerpt-range_from.widefat (backend.js, line 28)
```

In the DOM, the new class `hasDatepicker` never get's added.

Comment: Did you register your script or styles before enqueueing it?

Comment: What does the developer tools console say in terms of errors?

Comment: @songdogtech I forgot to mention that, sorry. Theres nothing on the console.

Comment: @Raja67 no, I did not. Because I used the same code in a different theme and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Please re-read my question. I added some code and more informations

Comment: I think you need to bind with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Which object and which event do you mean?

Comment: I copied all my code to jsfiddle and everything works there...

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, in backend you may use:

```
jQuery('#something')
```

instead of

```
$('#something')
```

Comment: This is most likely the problem. WordPress loads jQuery in no conflict mode so you lose the $() in favor of jQuery().

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can be a selector issue. Try making your selector more specific for the widget in the sidebars:

Something like :

> $('#widgets-right #widget-so_calendar_excerpt-range_from')

could work.

But, if you create a second instance of the widget, it can break again, because of the multiple same ids.