# jQuery .change() Event Bubbling in WP Admin

Tags: jquery, wp-admin

Experiencing some very odd behaviour in WP Admin, specifically on widgets.php. I'm creating a custom widget, and am writing some simple JS. This is the hook I'm using to enqueue my JS:

```
/**
 * Enqeue the admin-side JS.
 */
function ni_list_products_scripts( $hook ) {
    if( $hook == 'widgets.php' ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'list_products_scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/widget-list-products.js', 'jquery' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'ni_list_products_scripts' );
```

And the actual JS file (simplified just to show the issue):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#ni_list_products_search").on('change', function(e) {
        console.log('change');
    });
});
```

My end goal is to filter a list of posts, based on the text inputs value, but the .change() event doesn't seem to fire at all. I've tried using .change() as well to no avail.

I'm totally stumped. I know the selector is right, and I know the script is being run. In my debugging I tried to do some basic stuff to #ni_list_products_search, and `$("#ni_list_products_search").remove();` does nothing as well.

Just so I cover all the bases, the input I'm trying to target: `<input class="widefat" id="ni_list_products_search" type="text">`.

I have no idea where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you see the script including in the source? Is it the correct URL for the script? Can you run `jQuery("#ni_list_products_search").remove();` from the console?

Comment: @SeamusLeahy, the script is included and running, so yes the URL is correct. Running `jQuery("#ni_list_products_search").remove();` from the console did work.

Comment: What happens when you run `jQuery("#ni_list_products_search").remove();` from the Javascript console? (http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/google-chrome-dev-tools-how-to-use-the-console-panel/)

Comment: If you add the widget, then reload the page, does it work? You JS will not bind to new widget instances.

Comment: @SeamusLeahy it doesn't work for new or previously placed widgets.

Comment: Similar issue: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130925/jquery-does-not-work-in-widget-backend

Answer (score -2):

try $("selector").live("change", function(){ /*Your code here*/ });

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: .live() is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, replaced with .on(). This code example is essentially the exact same as what I've already posted.